# Drywall texture used?

Tags: drywall, painting, patching-drywall, texture

Can someone please help me identify the texture in this picture?

I’ve been patching a few holes around the house and cannot get the texture to match no matter what I do!

Notice how’s very little texture if any against the wood framing (*by window and doors*).

I’d appreciate any insight, thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: sand the new work, feathering the edges, then use a rough surface roller to repaint.

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't look like drywall texture to me. It looks like stippling from a heavy-nap roller. The reason you don't see it along the trim is because a brush was used there.

When you paint, do the brush edging, then immediately roll over it as close as you can to the trim. This will minimize the smooth strip.

Comment: A wide piece of masking/painter's tape on the edge of the trim will help protect it from the roller.

Comment: I've typically seen this referred to as an *orange peel texture*.

Comment: Orange peel is a sprayed texture. This ain't that. Granted, this _does_ look more like actual orange peel than that. :)